# Sending notifications to your Friends in Pinax, Django

Tags: notifications, pinax

Currently, I am sending notifications to all Users in the database. How can I get the list of all my friends, so then notifications would be sent to all my friends?

```
if new and notification:
    notification.send(User.objects.all().exclude(id=self.owner.id),
                "listing_new",
                {'listing':self, },
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
from friends.models import Friendship
if new and notification:
    notification.send(Friendship.objects.friends_for_user(self.owner.id), "listing_new", {'listing':self, }, )
```